# How do I put a package into the Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: development, application-development, packaging, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)

I've created a Python application for Ubuntu. How do I package it and submit it for possible inclusion in the `universe` repository?