# How can I add my application to the Ubuntu repository?

Tags: repository, packaging, deb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I put a package into the Ubuntu repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167/how-do-i-put-a-package-into-the-ubuntu-repositories)

I've just made a project called tgames and want to add it at the ubuntu repository...
(multiverse or universe or anything)

Can I do this or should I create a ppa???

Answer (score 4):

The process for getting new packages into archive is outlined here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a ppa via your launchpad account, activate it on your profile page, sign the Ubuntu Cod of Conduct, then start uploading your source package.

For more in-depth detail:

https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

There are hyperlinks embedded in the instructions that will link on how to access your profile page, signing the code of conduct, & upload your source code.